# SQL server issue or connection / code issues?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having this problem for some time and wondering if anyone could offer some guidance? My PHP (Version 5.5.35) / MYSQL (version 5.7) code is below but after searching for a resolution I'm not convinced the issue lies with the code itself, and could be a problem with the sql server, although I'm fairly new to this so not sure exactly how to resolve.

**The Problem:**

A PHP / MYSQL query (SELECT * FROM table) returns an array but misses the first row in the browser (except when I load in the browser first - see below). Includes every row after, but always misses the first.

I've checked this online numerous times and the cause of this is usually in the PHP code and calling 'mysqli_fetch_array();' twice. However, this is not the case and cannot be the problem anyway, as the half solution below indicates.

**The temporary solution:**

I've managed to narrow this down and find a cause (or one cause at least). It seems to be related to how I use the browser and command line to process the request. If I create a SQL table and do the select all command straight into the command line, the table shows fine below, but when I then load in the browser it misses the first row. Conversely, if I then amend the table (alter table command of some kind. eg add column and then drop column commands, or create an entirely new table) and then go straight to the browser (without select all in the command line), it loads fine in the browser with the first row included. When I then go back to the command line and type the select all command, it shows empty set with warnings. I then try to show the warnings and it says lost connection??!!

To summarise, a select all command in the command line causes the browser to load the results but missing the first; but loading in the browser first works fine (all rows) but shows empty set in the command line after...

**The code**

PHP / SQL

```
<?php
require('../../connect.php');
$q = "SELECT * FROM table_1" or die("Unable to select data".mysqli_error($connection));
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die("Unable to select data".mysqli_error($connection));
if ($r) 
{   
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r )) 
{
echo '<br>'.$row['id'].'|'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['colour'].'|'.$row['price'];
}
}
mysqli_close( $dbc );
exit();
```

PHP Connect file

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password')
OR die (mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'database');
mysqli_set_charset( $dbc, 'utf8' );
?>
```

MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM table;  
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN temp INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN temp;
```

**EXAMPLES**

When processing (SELECT * FROM table;) from the browser **before** doing the same request in the command line beforehand

```
1 | object1 | yellow | £50
2 | object2 | blue | £100
3 | object3 | red | £60
```

When processing (SELECT * FROM table;) from the browser **after** doing the same request in the command line

```
2 | object2 | blue | £100
3 | object3 | red | £60
```

Error message in command line (when loading in browser first)

```
*Empty set, 26624 warnings (0.00 sec)*
SHOW WARNINGS;
*Error 2013 (HY000) Lost connection to MYSQL server during query*
```

Comment: Add ` or die("Unable to select data".mysqli_error($connection))` with `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)` instead of when you are assigning the query into a variable.

Comment: Missing first record: The command line lives in a different session, so a relation here should not exist: Remove the sql-server tag from your post please, add which version of mysql you are using (because if this is a bug in mysql, that is the information which is needed).

Comment: @Arif Have added the 'die' function.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen Thanks. Have added v 5.7 SQL. Server tag has been removed.

Comment: Have you oversimplified your actual code for the sake of this example? _(there is no apparent purpose for `$results_array` or `$row_array`)_

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes, sorry but the above code does behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer for the `Error 2013`: I don't know what php config you are running, but look at the memory settings in there. Also you might want to add `LIMIT` to your query to limit the number of results, and thus prevent the 2013 error.

Also test the following:

```
  SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC
```

It looks like the missing record issue might just be data access related: SQL is not guaranteed to give the same order of the records every time. So when they are already in memory, it is possible that a different memory block is available first, before the one you normally see. The only way to guarantee the data order is by using the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the ORDER BY but same issue. I'm using PHP Version 5.5.35. Not completely sure how to use LIMIT so will need to look that one up.

Comment: Interesting. I only have three rows in the table (it's a test table) and select * returns the 2013 error but select * with the limit 3 shows all results...

Comment: Hum, you are narrowing down the issue (good work!): You might want to move your question over to the database forum: It looks like you are hitting a bug in either the connection driver or in MySQL itself. Optional: Just replace MySQL with MariaDB 10.1.x and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Also check your webserver log files for errors: There can be something interesting there.

Comment: Thanks again. I've flagged for it to be moved to the database forum. If not, I will try MariaDB. Had a look through the logs and just trying to understand.